# QList statement

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qtreewidgetitem

I'm working with with QTreeViewItem and also QList.

What I'm doing in my C++/Qt app is to build a TreeView with multiple elements inside.

When clicking on a dedicated action, I'm checking which item of my tree view is selected and get the item associated name. This is working fine, but prior to any action, I need to know if I had selected something or not. But there is no way to test if the result is 0 or any other value.

```
void MainWindow::onAddFolderAction() {
    uint32_t index;
    uint32_t parent_id;

    QList<QTreeWidgetItem*> item = MyTree->selectedItems();
    if (item == 0) { // ISSUE
        parent_id = 0;
    } else {
        QString str = item[0]->text(0);
        QByteArray latin_str = str.toLatin1();
        char *utf8_text = latin_str.data();

        index = m_device.getIdByName(utf8_text);
        // parent_id = m_device.getIdParent(index);
    }

    m_device.CreateNewFolder("New Folder", index);
    MyTree->clear();
    DisplayTree(0, 0);
}
```

I need to make sure that I am not managing an action on an unallocated or unfiled item pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The [`selectedItems()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#selectedItems) function returns a list of items. Since that's a `QList`, you can just use [`item.empty()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#isEmpty) to see if it is empty.